# Customize hardcoded jquery context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

My working jquery code for displaying context menu is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '#mytv a',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
            },
            items: {
                "edit": {
                    name: "Closing on Click",
                    icon: "edit",
                    callback: function () { return true; }
                },
                "cut": {
                    name: "Open after Click",
                    icon: "cut",
                    callback: function () { return false; }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Instead of hardcoded Menu I want menu to be displayed from this:

```
   <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
            <li class="copy"><a href="#add">Add</a></li>
            <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>  
            <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>
            <li class="quit separator"><a href="#cancel">Cancel</a></li>
            </ul>
```

I am not good with with jquery any help would be strongly appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of context menu plugins. Provide link to documentation for the one you are using along with more detailed description of your problem

Comment: http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html I got this code from here

Comment: And the specific problem is?

Comment: I want <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu"> to come as menu not hardcoded menu